# Android Handler NullPointerException (while sending Message)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, handler

I have a problem with `Handler`. This is what my app does:

1. New Thread is created.
2. Thread downloads data, then puts them in a message.
3. Thread sends message to handler.

And here the problem begins. According to logs app throws `NullPointerException` in this line:

```
replyTo.sendMessage(msg);
```

Sometimes everything is OK, sometimes it's not. Handler is placed before creating a new thread. This is code for handler:

```
Handler responseHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        ad.dismiss();
        populateListWithVideos(msg);
        };
};
```

Do you have any ideas why is this happening?

EDIT: Here's my Logcat.
How to read it:

- "Powstała nowa biblioteka" - new ArrayList has been created
- "Array" - JSONArray has been recieved
- "Obiekt"/"Tytuł" + number - Object/String from JSONArray has been recieved (number - an object number)
- "Dodano do biblioteki" - strings recieved from Object have been added to array as Video
- "Nowa biblioteka" - new Library created from ArrayList
- "Serializable" - Library serialized into bundle
- "Otrzymano wiadomość" - Message obtained using Message.obtain()
- "Ustalono wiadomość" - Bundle put into Message using Message.setData()
- "Wysłano wiadomość" - Message sent to Handler

  ```
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Powstała nowa biblioteka
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Array
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Obiekt0
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Tytuł0
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Dodano do biblioteki
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Obiekt1
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Tytuł1
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Dodano do biblioteki
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Obiekt2
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Tytuł2
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Dodano do biblioteki
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Obiekt3
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Tytuł3
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Dodano do biblioteki
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Obiekt4
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Tytuł4
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Dodano do biblioteki
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Obiekt5
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Tytuł5
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Dodano do biblioteki
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Obiekt6
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Tytuł6
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Dodano do biblioteki
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Obiekt7
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Tytuł7
  02-07 13:17:13.885: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Dodano do biblioteki
  ...
  02-07 13:17:13.905: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Obiekt48
  02-07 13:17:13.905: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Tytuł48
  02-07 13:17:13.905: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Dodano do biblioteki
  02-07 13:17:13.905: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Obiekt49
  02-07 13:17:13.905: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Tytuł49
  02-07 13:17:13.905: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Dodano do biblioteki
  02-07 13:17:13.905: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Nowa biblioteka
  02-07 13:17:13.905: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Serializable
  02-07 13:17:13.905: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Otrzymano wiadomość
  02-07 13:17:13.905: D/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Ustalono wiadomość
  02-07 13:17:13.905: E/Ignaś TV(24913): Thread-6447| Koniec listy //Error
  02-07 13:17:13.905: E/Ignaś TV(24913): java.lang.NullPointerException
  02-07 13:17:13.905: E/Ignaś TV(24913):  at         com.ignas.ignastv.service.task.GetData.run(GetData.java:142)
  02-07 13:17:13.905: E/Ignaś TV(24913):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
  ```

Comment: can you post the logcat?

Comment: maybe your 2. step failes and then it puts null in the message

Comment: You need to post the logcat, other wise it's a guessing game. But, my guess would be that ad is null so when you call ad.dismiss() it throws the exception. Try: if(ad != null) {ad.dismiss();}